# Obtener fecha en formato "05 Dic 2020" en lugar de "05 dic. 2020" en Java

Tags: java, datetime

Estoy tratando de formatear una fecha en java con el siguiente código:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy", new Locale(es, ES));
System.out.println(date.format(formatter));
```

Pero lo que obtengo de respuesta es ejemplo: "05 dic. 2020", he intentado con todos los country y con todos me sale igual, ¿alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para que el mes tenga mayúscula inicial, no tener el punto y que quede en español?
ya que si cambio el locale por Locale(en, US) ya si me trae el mes en el formato que quiero "05 Dec 2020" pero en inglés.

Muchas gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso no creo se pueda usando un `Locale` diferente pueda funcionar, incluso puede ser la configuración de tu idioma en la pc, por lo tanto te sugiero  usar otro método para cambiar el mes:

```
  private static String changeMonth(String myDate){
        String result = myDate.replace( myDate.split("\\s+")[1],myDate.split("\\s+")[1].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + myDate.split("\\s+")[1].substring(1)).replace(".","");
        return result;
    }
```

Lo llamarías de esta forma:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy", new Locale(es, ES));
    System.out.println(changeMonth(date.format(formatter)));
```

para obtener como salida:

```
05 Dic 2020
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente cómo dices usando el Locale no podía conseguir lo que necesitaba, con el código que pusiste me funciona perfecto y es exactamente lo que buscaba!

Answer (score 0):

Como ves, me sale en español sin incluir en el código la localización, por lo que puede deberse algún tipo de configuración sobre el idioma en tu equipo o en tu entorno de desarrollo, no?

Yo obtengo los siguientes resultados :

```
    DateTimeFormatter fecha0 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss: " + fecha0.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss-> 26/05/21 22:45:21

```
    DateTimeFormatter fecha1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("dd/MMM/yyy HH:mm:ss: " + fecha1.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MMM/yyy HH:mm:ss-> 26/may/21 22:45:21

```
    DateTimeFormatter fecha2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMMM/yy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("dd/MMMM/yy HH:mm:ss: " + fecha2.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MMMM/yy HH:mm:ss-> 26/mayo/21 22:45:22

```
    DateTimeFormatter fecha3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss: " + fecha3.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss-> 26/05/2021 22:45:22

```
    DateTimeFormatter fecha4 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm");
    System.out.println("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm: " + fecha4.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm-> 26/may/2021 22:45

```
    DateTimeFormatter fecha5 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm");
    System.out.println("dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss: " + fecha5.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss-> 26/mayo/2021 10:45

```
    DateTimeFormatter fecha6 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm");
    System.out.println("EEEE, dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss: " + fecha6.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

EEEE, dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss: miércoles 26/mayo/2021 11:01

Answer (score 0):

Curiosamente con Locale en formato Java (con guión bajo) sale como quieres:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.forLanguageTag("es_ES"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date())); // 26 May 2021
```