# ¿Cómo obtener año anterior de una fecha en java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

tengo una date de entrada con este formato yyyy-MM-dd y quiero obtener el año anterior a esa fecha, es decir si recibo 2020-03-23 quiero obtener 2019-03-23, cómo puedo hacer esto en java?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Mírate éste enlace donde se trata el tema de fecha en java https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455212/obtener-fecha-en-formato-05-dic-2020-en-lugar-de-05-dic-2020-en-java/455234#455234

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fecha_salida,fecha_entrada="2020-03-23";
    String[] aux=fecha_entrada.split("-"); 
    //Split separa el string fecha cada vez que encuentre un "-"
    //retornando { "2020", "03", "23" } ,que será asignado a la matriz aux
    int anio_anterior=Integer.parseInt(aux[0])-1;//Restamos una unidad al año actual
    
    fecha_salida=anio_anterior+"-"+aux[1]+"-"+aux[2];//tu respuesta
    System.out.println(fecha_salida);
}
```

Comment: Está seria la fuente , lista para personalizar. Recomendaria que te asegures que el dato que recibas sea una fecha , puede que por un error la fecha este incorrecta ,una manera de validar seria con el tamaño del string  ,fecha_entrada debe tener 10 caracteres por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo con el tipo Date el cual es algo raro el año comienza en "1900" así que si le insertas como año el valor "1" te lo toma como 1901 el mes comienza en "0" y el día es igual espero que la definición de este método de ayude. Suerte!!
Definicion:

```
public static Date getDateOneYearBefore(String date){
        Date one_year_before= new Date(); //It is the current date
        
        String [] separar=date.split("-");//Split yor date "2020-03-23" to ["2020","03","23"]
        int year=Integer.parseInt(separar[0])-1900; //we subtract the year and "1900" because Date begging in that year
        //for example the year "120" for Date is 2020
        int month=Integer.parseInt(separar[1])-1;// the month begging on "0" which is January
        int day=Integer.parseInt(separar[2]);//It is the same day
        int year_before=year-1;//get one year before
        
        one_year_before.setYear(year_before);//set the year that you want
        one_year_before.setMonth(month);//set month
        one_year_before.setDate(day);//set day
        
        //setting to hour 00:00
        one_year_before.setMinutes(0);
        one_year_before.setHours(0);
        
        return one_year_before;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes: pon el código _como texto, con formato_. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.